# private advertisement / answer table

Tags: database-design

I search a way to design this dataflow

I want to create advertisement

User see this advertisement and answer it. I can see all user answers.

User can only see their answer and mine.

I can surely do it with that table

```
CREATE TABLE ADVERTISEMENT(
 ADVERTISEMENT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 TITLE VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
 STATE_ID  INT NOT NULL
 DATE_CREATION DATE,
 USERS_ID INT,
 PARENT_ID INT,
);
```

but i search a way to avoid heavy query on database.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on the column(s) you want to search for. I can't quite figure out from your design which column that is (it would be the advertiser identifier in your record - USERS_ID?)

With an index, the database will immediately know the exact record to go to, and it will not place any load on the database. This is what databases are for.

In practice, with a small number of records (e.g. thousands), the load will be insignificant in any case.